# struct containing lambdas which modify values via reference

Tags: c++, lambda

Here's a simple program which uses a `value_control` struct to store lambdas which modify an integer variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct value_control
{
    std::function<void(void)> increase;
    std::function<void(void)> decrease;
};

int main()
{   
    auto a = 123;

    value_control a_control{ [&]() { a += 1; }, [&]() { a -= 1; } };

    a_control.decrease(); std::cout << a << std::endl;

    a_control.increase(); std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
122
123
```

Here's a version which abstracts out the `value_control` creation into `make_numeric_control`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct value_control
{
    std::function<void(void)> increase;
    std::function<void(void)> decrease;
};

int main()
{   
    auto make_numeric_control = [](int& var, int change)
    {
        return value_control
        {
            [&]() { var += change; },
            [&]() { var -= change; }
        };
    };

    auto a = 123;

    auto a_control = make_numeric_control(a, 1);

    a_control.decrease(); std::cout << a << std::endl;

    a_control.increase(); std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

This version of the program does not behave like the first:

```
-19620773
178
```

Any suggestions for how to write `make_numeric_control` such that it the second version works like the first version?

Comment: `[&,change]() { var += change; }`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Perfect... Thank you Piotr!

Comment: Note that your struct does not contain lambas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you capture `change` by reference as well as `var` due to the `[&]` capture specifier. `change` will be destructed when `make_numeric_control` exits, so inside the closure it will be a dangling reference.

You can fix this by capturing `var` by reference and `change` by value:

```
    return value_control
    {
        [&var, change]() { var += change; },
        [&var, change]() { var -= change; }
    };
```